# Spark app killed after waiting for resurces

Tags: apache-spark

My Spark application is submitted to standalone cluster.

Because no resources left (two other job running) I got msg: "WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources" and app is killed after 55 minutes.

How could I change this time ?

I would like to increase it to give the application a chance to run when other tasks are finished and free up resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the spark.excludeOnFailure.timeout parameter, the default is 1h.

Comment: Unfortunately it not help.